# Ubuntu 15.04 + nodm – Continual restarts

Tags: ubuntu, startup, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm attempting to have nodm start a kiosk application at boot time.

It successfully begins the application, but then dies / restarts after initiation, landing me back at console.  It then periodically attempts to restart after an increasing amount of time.

Starting the application manually via root works as expected.

auth.log reports the following:

```
Jul  7 13:56:33 bp1 nodm[708]: restarting session
Jul  7 13:56:33 bp1 nodm[1594]: Successful su on ??? for root by root
Jul  7 13:56:33 bp1 nodm[1594]: pam_unix(nodm:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  7 13:56:33 bp1 systemd-logind[640]: New session c3 of user root.
Jul  7 13:56:33 bp1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  7 13:56:38 bp1 nodm[1594]: pam_unix(nodm:session): session closed for user root
Jul  7 13:56:38 bp1 nodm[708]: X session 1594 quit with status 0
Jul  7 13:56:38 bp1 nodm[708]: sending X server 1591 the TERM signal
Jul  7 13:56:38 bp1 nodm[708]: session lasted less than 7 seconds: sleeping 30 seconds before restarting it
```

/etc/default/nodm is set as follows:

```
# nodm configuration

# Set NODM_ENABLED to something different than 'false' to enable nodm
NODM_ENABLED=true

# User to autologin for
NODM_USER=root

# First vt to try when looking for free VTs
NODM_FIRST_VT=7

# X session
NODM_XSESSION=/root/.xsession

# Options for the X server
NODM_X_OPTIONS='-nolisten tcp'

# If an X session will run for less than this time in seconds, nodm will wait an
# increasing bit of time before restarting the session.
NODM_MIN_SESSION_TIME=5
```

.xsession currently contains:

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

/var/app/electron /var/app/project_contents/
```

Additionally, I've posted a video of the flickering to:
http://youtu.be/M5ZvBbhJlCY

Any pointers on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: display your .xsession file as well please.

Comment: This appears to have something to do with accessing USB.  Removing USB accessors prevents the error.

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do w/ nodm.  Electron was running Johnny-Five in REPL mode.  Disabling REPL mode when instantiating Johnny-Five addressed the issue.  It's 5:54 in the morning.